# Getting strange results from view query

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I am testing a database that was written by someone else who left company.
Here what it looks like:

[image]

Here is the query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
       bcprod.product.item_number,
       bcprod.product.product_id,
       bcprod.product_price.price1,
       bcprod.product_price.price2,
       bcprod.product_price.price3,
       bcprod.product_price.price4,
       bcprod.product_price.option_value_id,
       bcprod.product_option.weight_class,
       bcprod.product_option.status
FROM bcprod.product
     INNER JOIN bcprod.product_price ON bcprod.product_price.product_id = bcprod.product.product_id
     INNER JOIN bcprod.product_option ON bcprod.product_option.product_id = bcprod.product.product_id
WHERE bcprod.product.is_sale = 1
  AND bcprod.product.status = 1
  AND bcprod.product_option.status = 1
 AND bcprod.product.product_id = 1
```

The problem is when I check the weight column in product_option I get 815 rows back compared to 285 with weight not checked(when testing without the last AND in where clause).  I save the design view every time I make a change - I even refresh it afterwards.  I checked for duplicates in both the product_price and product_option table because I thought there was something wrong with option_value_id and product_id:

```
select bcprod.product_price.product_id,
       bcprod.product_price.option_value_id,
       Count(*)
       from bcprod.product_price
group by bcprod.product_price.product_id,
         bcprod.product_price.option_value_id
having (Count(*)>1)
```

I found no duplicates - I need some advice as to how to fix this please - I am not that good at working with databases.
The option_value_id gets doubled and if there was only two rows for an item - after checking weight it doubles to like 4 rows - as an example?

Incorrect Data:
[image]

correct data - without weight:

[image]

Comment: FYI [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.

Comment: Also Whitespace and Linebreaks are paramount to making readable text; not just in code. Please get into the habit of making good use of both. Poor/bad formatting is not going to help you or others when you need to be able to quickly read and understand your code. Using indentation and line breaks really helps easily distinguish specific code blocks and sections, and make finding errors far easier when a line only contains 10's of characters, rather than 100's. Don't over use parenthesis (`()`) either; each clause in the `WHERE` does not need to be wrapped in them

Comment: _I found no duplicates_ Then why do you have DISTINCT? And you REALLY need to add short (but not cryptic) aliases and use them to make your code readable. Encourage others to help you by making an effort to write (and post) well-written code.

Comment: You clearly have a one to many relationship here. That image shows that a `product` is related to *many* `product_option`s.

Comment: I was just testing - Distinct made no difference with my problem.

Comment: @Larnu - True about the one to many - but weight is part of the option just like weight_class.

Comment: That doesn't mean anything to me, @duerzd696 , we don't have any data to have context. You're getting more rows than  in your table `product_price` because you have a one to many `JOIN`. If you `JOIN` 1 row to 2 rows you don't get 1 row, you get 2.

Comment: Agreed, the join is multiplying your rows. You need to decide how to show this. Do you want to aggregate different weights, do you want to show only one (if so which one)?

Comment: the weight should be different when compared to option_value_id as shown in the correct data image as well as the prices.

Comment: Would providing the script for tables be of some help - I could gather that up as well?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: If you look at incorrect data image even the weights are wrong comared to option_value_id.  Option_value_id = 2 , should have the same weight listed, as well as for id 4.  So how could it be the join when im still joining the same as in the correct image data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by modifying the query with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        bcprod.product.item_number,
        bcprod.product.product_id, 
        bcprod.product_price.price1, 
        bcprod.product_price.price2,
        bcprod.product_price.price3, 
        bcprod.product_price.price4, 
        bcprod.product_option.status AS option_status, 
        bcprod.product_option.weight_class,
        bcprod.product.category_id,
        bcprod.product_option.weight, 
        bcprod.product_price.option_value_id,
        bcprod.product.weight AS accessesory_weight, 
        bcprod.product.weight_class AS accessesory_weightclass, 
        bcprod.product.price, 
        bcprod.product.status AS main_status,
        bcprod.product.is_sale, 
        bcprod.product.is_accessory,
        bcprod.product.image, 
        bcprod.option_value.option_name
FROM            bcprod.product INNER JOIN
        bcprod.product_price ON bcprod.product_price.product_id = 
        bcprod.product.product_id INNER JOIN
        bcprod.product_option ON bcprod.product_option.product_id = 
        bcprod.product.product_id AND bcprod.product_price.option_value_id = 
        bcprod.product_option.option_value_id INNER JOIN
        bcprod.option_value ON bcprod.product_price.option_value_id = 
        bcprod.option_value.option_value_id AND 
        bcprod.product_option.option_value_id = 
        bcprod.option_value.option_value_id
 WHERE        (bcprod.product.status = 1)
```

If someone could come with better idea - I'm all ears.
The problem was in last join - adding the AND.